# Return blanks when search field is left blank Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have created an excel Workbook that allows me to search for products.  For example, I enter "bag" into cell B2 and hit enter, Cells B5:B24 return all results with "bag" in it from the product list.

The problem i am having is that when the field is left blank and i hit enter, the formula returns ALL products to B5:B24.  Can i get Cells B5:B24 to return blanks or "" when the search field B2 is left blank?

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Search and Req Form'!$B$2,C2)),MAX('Search and Req Form'!$D$1:D1)+1,0)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just put an additional IF statement in front if it:

=IF($B$2="","",*Formula*)